# What is a Point?

Tags: mysql, spatial, point

I'm trying to work with spatial data types which I find to be not so widely understood on the internet as compared to other programming topics.

I have a table which contains objects on a map. Coordinates go from 0,0 to infinity in any direction, theoretically. There can not be more than 1 object at a point on the map so I designed the table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `map_objects` (
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` point NOT NULL,
  `type` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`position`(25)),
  SPATIAL KEY `position_2` (`position`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

So far so good, I can select objects using the various geometry functions provided by the spatial extension, but I don't really understand what's inside the `Point`, why is it 25 bytes long? Surprisingly it is not documented pretty much anywhere. I found some old code I used in another project where I used to fetch the binary points and extract the coordinates in my application logic (for some reason):

```
unpack('x/x/x/x/co/Lt/dlat/dlng', $point);
```

Which tells me that the first four bytes are empty, then there is a character, a long and the doubles for the coordinates. I highly doubt the bytes in the beginning are actually unused, probably the one I copied this code from just didn't need them. Whatever the case is I can currently select an object on the map by only knowing the coordinates:

```
SELECT * FROM map_objects WHERE position = ST_GeomFromText('Point(1 1)')
```

Which in turn should mean that all the bytes besides the coordinates can be generated by MySQL at the time of execution, which means they are insignificant? What is the *point* of having them in the `Point` column?

Additionally in theory it should be possible to select a record by providing the 25 binary bytes and using the equals operator, but my attempts actually failed to do so, I just got empty results back, why is that?

Comment: Are you really asking how values of the MySQL `Point` type are encoded?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Essentially. I, as well as a lot of other people, may not be so proficient as to dig into the source of such a complicated program. I spent quite some time searching for this information and I couldn't find it, what's the harm in asking? I would like to understand the work principles of the tools I'm using, I believe that's what separates good engineers from bad ones.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I just assumed so as your tone seemed rather mocky, I apologize.

Comment: Oh, sorry I can actually see how it would be read that way. I meant it like "instead of asking what Point is, are you *actually* asking how it works" ... not "are you _honestly_ asking this question? what's wrong with you?" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [well-known binary format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-wkb-format):

> For example, a WKB value that corresponds to `POINT(1 -1)` consists of this sequence of 21 bytes, each represented by two hexadecimal digits:
>
> ```
> 0101000000000000000000F03F000000000000F0BF
> ```

> ```
> Component    | Size    | Value
> Byte order   | 1 byte  | 01
> WKB type     | 4 bytes | 01000000
> X coordinate | 8 bytes | 000000000000F03F
> Y coordinate | 8 bytes | 000000000000F0BF
> ```

Most of the starting bytes indicate that the geometry object is a `Point`.

Comment: But that seems redundant? It's clear that the column is of `Point` type, why would every single point need to contain 4 bytes that say it's a point?

Comment: @php_nub_qq I agree. I think it’s done that way because Point is a subclass of Geometry instead of a type.

Comment: But in the DDL it says `point` as if it were a type. It would make sense if all those types were basically treated as a single `geometry` type but then why define them as types separately. Just random thoughts.

Comment: @php_nub_qq You could try asking about what the difference is between classes and types is at https://dba.stackexchange.com/. I don't know enough about why MySQL chose to have classes to give a good answer.

Comment: @php_nub_qq wkb is not a mysql format. It is defined by Open Geospatial Consortium and is an ISO standard. Mysql simply implemented it complying with the standard's specifications.